# How to check value length with using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone I would like to ask how to check value's length from textbox ?

Here is my code :

```
@*<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["frm"]["txtCardNumber"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "" ) {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>*@
```

When I run my script yeap I got alert message but I'm trying to add property which control the texbox' input length.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `x.length` to get the length of the string:

```
if (x.length < 5) {
    alert('please enter at least 5 characters');
    return false;
}
```

Also I would recommend you using the [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) method instead of `document.forms["frm"]["txtCardNumber"]`.

So if you have an input field:

```
<input type="text" id="txtCardNumber" name="txtCardNumber" />
```

you could retrieve its value from the id:

```
var x = document.getElementById['txtCardNumber'].value;
```

Comment: +1 just please add a note about: `document.forms["frm"]["txtCardNumber"]`

Answer (score 2):

Still more better script would be:

```
<input type="text" name="txtCardNumber" id="txtCardNumber" />
```

And in the script:

```
if (document.getElementById(txtCardNumber).value.length < 5) {
    alert('please enter at least 5 characters');
    return false;
}
```